# Pandas: Check if row exists with certain values

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I have a two dimensional (or more) pandas DataFrame like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

Now suppose I have a numpy array like `np.array([2,3])` and want to check if there is any row in `df` that matches with the contents of my array. Here the answer should obviously true but eg. `np.array([1,2])` should return false as there is no row with both 1 in column A and 2 in column B.

Sure this is easy but don't see it right now.

Comment: there is both a row and a column with 1 , 2 so what exactly do you mean that there isn't?

Comment: Have you tried something like df.isin([1,2])?? It will output the booleans you need to find the rows that match fully and partially

Comment: @JohnRuddell: But there is no row which contains a 1 in column A and a 2 in column B. I am looking for semantics like the WHERE clause in SQL.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Turns out it is really easy, the following does the job here:

```
>>> ((df['A'] == 2) & (df['B'] == 3)).any()
True
>>> ((df['A'] == 1) & (df['B'] == 2)).any()
False
```

Maybe somebody comes up with a better solution which allows directly passing in the array and the list of columns to match.

Note that the parenthesis around `df['A'] == 2` are not optional since the `&` operator binds just as strong as the `==` operator.

Comment: The solution is good, however the performance is really bad when your data is huge. Try this: df.loc[(df['A'] == 2) & (df['B'] == 3)]. I tested on a dataset my solution's performance is 918 ms, and the one is 2.12 s.

Comment: @Navy Your solution can't be evaluated to True/False, you need to do something with the resulting DF

Comment: @Navy I'd love to see that as an answer if there is a way to evaluate to a Boolean value

Comment: @fgblomqvist @Xgongiveittoya Add an `any()` and an `all()` call to receive a Boolean. Like this: `df.loc[(df['A'] == 2) & (df['B'] == 3)].any().all()`

Answer (score 35):

an easier way is:

```
a = np.array([2,3])
(df == a).all(1).any()
```

Comment: This only works if the dimensionality is the same though, right? I.e. if the matching should be based on the first two columns of a five column DataFrame, wouldn't this fail?

Comment: that's trivial. replace `df` with `df[df.columns[:2]]`

Comment: Just in case you try it on a different data structure, try `(df == a).all(0).any()` as well

Answer (score 14):

If you also want to return the index where the matches occurred:

```
index_list = df[(df['A'] == 2)&(df['B'] == 3)].index.tolist()
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thankss

Answer (score 2):

To find rows where a single column equals a certain value:

```
df[df['column name'] == value]
```

To find rows where multiple columns equal different values, Note the inner ():

```
df[(df["Col1"] == Value1 & df["Col2"] == Value2 & ....)]
```

Comment: Although this is a correct answer, adding context to your code will make it clearer for others to understand! Also note that OP might be considering multiple columns and values.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution with dictionary

```py
def check_existance(dict_of_values, df):
    v = df.iloc[:, 0] == df.iloc[:, 0]
    for key, value in dict_of_values.items():
        v &= (df[key] == value)
    return v.any()
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

```py
this_row_exists = {'A':2, 'B':3}
check_existance(this_row_exists, df)
# True
```

```py
this_row_does_not_exist = {'A':2, 'B':5}
check_existance(this_row_does_not_exist, df)
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer that works with larger dataframes so you don't need to manually check for each columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define variables
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], columns=['A', 'B'])
a = np.array([2,3])

def check_if_np_array_is_in_df(df, a):
    # transform a into a dataframe
    da = pd.DataFrame(np.expand_dims(a,axis=0), columns=['A','B'])

    # drop duplicates from df
    ddf=df.drop_duplicates()

    result = pd.concat([ddf,da]).shape[0] - pd.concat([ddf,da]).drop_duplicates().shape[0]
    return result

print(check_if_np_array_is_in_df(df, a))
print(check_if_np_array_is_in_df(df, [1,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the row where the matches occurred:

```
resulting_row = df[(df['A'] == 2)&(df['B'] == 3)].values
```